# Error property ImageIndex from component TcxCheckListBox used in DLL

Tags: delphi

Testing:

1. Delphi 7 + DevExpress 6.59
2. Delphi 10.2 + DevExpress 18.1

if realise in application project

```
lst1.Items[0].ImageIndex := 0
```

result ok.

if realise in DLL project

```
lst1.Items[0].ImageIndex := 0
```

result critical error when redrawing component.

> Access violation at address 00000000. Read of address 00000000.

Same mistake if this parameter set design-time.

It is very good component visualisation link TcxCheckListBox + ImageList.
How to implementin DLL?

Project Aplication

```
unit uMain;
interface
uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    btnLoadForm: TButton;
    procedure btnLoadFormClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;
var
  Form1: TForm1;
  MyLoadForm : function (h : THandle) : Integer stdcall;
implementation
{$R *.dfm}
procedure TForm1.btnLoadFormClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  LibHandle : THandle;
  x : Integer;
begin
  LibHandle := LoadLibrary('MYDLL.DLL');
  if LibHandle >= 32 then
  begin
    @MyLoadForm := GetProcAddress(LibHandle,'MyLoadForm');
    if @MyLoadForm <> nil then
    begin
      x:= MyLoadForm(Application.Handle);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Project DLL

```
library myDll;
uses
  SysUtils,
  Classes,
  Dialogs,
  Forms,
  uDllForm in 'uDllForm.pas' {Form1},
  windows;
{$R *.res}
function MyLoadForm(AppHandle : THandle) : integer stdcall;
var
  dllform: TForm1;
begin
  Application.Handle := AppHandle;
  dllform:=TForm1.Create(Application);
  dllform.ShowModal;
  Result := 1;
end;
exports
  MyLoadForm;
begin
end.
```

unit form + TcxCheckListBox object

```
unit uDllForm;
interface
uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, cxGraphics, cxControls, cxLookAndFeels,
  cxLookAndFeelPainters, ImgList, CheckLst, cxContainer, cxEdit,
  cxCheckListBox;
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    btn1: TButton;
    lst1: TcxCheckListBox;
    il1: TImageList;
    procedure btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;
var
  Form1: TForm1;
implementation
{$R *.dfm}
procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var st : string;
begin
  lst1.Items[0].Text := 'test';
  lst1.Items[0].ImageIndex := 0;
end;
end.
```

Comment: Does the list have any items at all? If not, you wil get an Access Violation when you access Items[0].

Comment: Use the debugger. Load your DLL project into the IDE, and compile with debugging information. Set a breakpoint in the DLL form's `btn1Click` event. Use Run->Parameters from the menu, and specify the host application that loads your DLL, and then run your app and execute the code in that app until you get to btn1Click. The debugger will break, and you can step through the code. My first check would be to make sure that there was at least one item in `lst1.Items`, because if not accessing `Items[0]` is an error.

Comment: Should use an assert or an if to check that `cxCheckListBox1.Items.Count <> 0`

Comment: Number of elements = 1.
function lst1.Items [0] .Text: = 'test';
works correctly. if commit lst1.Items[0].ImageIndex := 0; then not error

Comment: This problem is produced on different computers, on different versions of delphi. The full text is provided in the question body.

Comment: if you use DevExpress controls in dll you must initialize the GDI+ library right after loading the DLL and finalize this library before releasing the DLL.
Please see [How to use DevExpress controls in DLL](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/KA18891/how-to-use-devexpress-controls-in-dll). Under attachments you can download example project.

Comment: Thank you, Branko. It's a very good recommendation.

Comment: It is not recommendation it is obligation if you use DX controls in dll. Otherwise it does not works at all.